# Идентификатор поддерживаемых bluetooth устройством профилей

Tags: winapi, windows, bluetooth

Интересует следующий вопрос: существует ли в Windows7(Microsoft bluetooth стек) идентификатор поддерживаемых устройством профилей(A2DP, HFP, OPP etc) в числовом виде: имеется ввиду, если сервис поддерживается, то в соответствующих позициях выставлены соответствующие флаги(1 или 0).
И если существует, как проще всего получить к нему доступ?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду Microsoft'овский bluetooth-стек?

Comment: Да именно он, забыл указать

Answer (score 1):

Никогда сам не делал, но, видимо, вам нужно использовать функции типа WSALookupService(Begin/Next/End) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362914(v=vs.85).aspx) и затем разбирать N-ое количество структур WSAQUERYSET.

Comment: Этот способ плох во первых огромным временем выполнения WSALookupService(даже для одного сервиса, тк необходимо посылать запросы на устройство), во вторых сложностью обработки результатов и их избыточностью